# Wordpress unable to establish connection to mySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a new wordpress site on my local server.
I've added the correct credentials in the config.php but when I try to begin the WP installation process I get the error message:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'x'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/httpd/html/xxx/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1518

In wp-db.php line 1518 the code is:

```
$this->dbh = mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );
```

I'm not sure what this error is telling me to fix.  I tried actually writing the credentials in where it says dbhost, dbuser etc.  Tried writing the credentials minus the password as some solutions has suggested but it still does not work.

Also granted all privileges to the user on the database but still same error message.  If anyone can help that'd be great.

Comment: Did you try to create a simple connection on another file in the same directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion the problem is not in WP files, but it is in your DB server settings.

Create a file called test_connection.php and save it in the same folder of your wp installation (where you have your index).

In that file write the following code, save it and then launch it to test your connection to the database.

In the code just change USERNAME, PASSWORD and DB_NAME with yours.

UPDATE

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DB_NAME");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
  echo "Ok, you're connected"; }
?>
```

This is the first test I suggest you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I made the file and uploaded it but it is returning a blank page with the console message:  The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  Not sure if i did this correctly.

Comment: @sp312 try now, I've update the code adding the first line:  
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: I'm sorry, there was another error on last row. I missed a ";" after connected"

Comment: I've tried again and now am getting this weird message with different characters J���
5.7.10�w��+i8VQ�ÿ÷�ÿ����������!|UjszK~}�mysql_native_password���ÿ„Got packets out of order.  But yeah, definitely think you're write and the problem is with my db settings and not WP files...

Comment: What OS you use ? and what did you used to get your local server ?
On OSX I suggest you to instal MAMP.
On Windows you could try WAMP Server http://www.wampserver.com/en/#download-wrapper

Comment: Im using Yosemite.  I was just running it off my machine for localhost.  I thought I could just install wp on a dedicated server i have with my hosting company.  They dont have a control panel so have been working in terminal to set things up.  Obviously dont know what im doing haha but will start over again after installing MAMP and reading up more on databases and servers.  Thank you for getting me in the right direction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99440/discussion-between-gianca-and-sp312).